# Unique and reproducible identifier for Java Object (Eclipe EMF's resources and model elments)

Tags: java, identity, uniqueidentifier, eclipse-emf

I've been googling around for a solution, and read a lot of questions/answers here in SOF, but didn't find anything I could use.

My problem is the following: I need to uniquely identify EMF elements across different machines. The lowest level known superclass would be org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Notifier, as the elements may be resources and/or model elements.

The Id should be reproducible at runtime across the different machines (I may have to calculate the ID both in the client and server having only a reference to the Java object). I have no access to the source code, I cannot modify the models (files), and not all model elements have a uuids.

As the Id should be reproducible across different machines, I cannot use *hashCode()* (any form). I thought on using MD5 hashes, but I cannot figure out what to use as the seed of the MD5 hash that would make it **unique** (to some extent) and **reproducible** at the same time.

All help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I kind of found a solution.
I use different ID's for EObjects and for Resources:

- For EObjects, I get their fragment URI (their path inside the containing resource), make it a String, and use that as the seed to the MD5 hash. It turns out that the result of `fragmentURI().toString()` looks amazingly similar to what EMF generates as the UUID. :-)
- For Resources, I get the file's contents (model files are generally XMI/XML files) and calculate the MD5 hash on those.

The solution is a little heavy, specially the resource piece, but I make it up by minimizing the calls to the ID's generation algorithm, so it is ok for me. What it is is unique and reproducible across machines, which is what I needed.

Hope this helps someone in the future.